# Gem required for running rails console on Snow Leopard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Have tried to run rails console but when I try to run a simple command like:

"foobar".length

I get a "Command not found" error. IRB runs fine.

Do I need to download a gem and do a bundle install to run rails console? If so, what gem?

Am running Rails 3.0.9

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your rails console didn't actually start properly but tried to start and killed itself because of some error. The error you receive sound more like it's coming from your shell (e.g. bash).

Try to start your console with `bundle exec rails console`. If there are errors, please post them here.

Comment: Thank you. Here is the error after running the bundle exec rails console command: ~ pdenlinger$ bundle exec rails console
Could not locate Gemfile